# Is there some method to get data from multiple tables with foreign key in Web API with LINQ to SQL Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql

I have some relationship tables like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX3vK.jpg), but I don't know how to get data from it in web API controller:

```cs
public IQueryable<what_table> Get()
{
     DatabasePelniDataContext db = new DatabasePelniDataContext();
     var data = db.what_tables.Select(p => p);
     return data;
}
```

Also, I want to know how to do CRUD with tables that have the foreign key in web API.

Comment: what data you want to get?

Comment: Please follow this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wow5PvLz-gY

Comment: I got an error exception that is say `Object graph for type 'namespace.Models.data_admin' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled.`